# react-scroll doesn't work with tailwind overflow-y-scroll using Next.js

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, overflow, react-scroll

I'm trying to implement a full page scroll with tailwind but when i do this my react-scroll link to doesn't work. It works when I remove overflow-y-scroll, but then the full page scroll with tailwind snap doesn't work. My code:

```js
'use client'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Link } from 'react-scroll'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <div className='snap-y snap-mandatory h-screen w-screen overflow-y-scroll'>
        <div className="snap-start bg-beige h-screen">
          <div className='flex justify-between pl-3 pr-3'>
            <div className='relative h-14 w-14 md:h-16 md:w-16'>
              <Image
                src="/logo-gray.png"
                layout="fill"
                objectFit="cover"
                alt="Logo"
              />
            </div>
            <div className='flex items-center'>
              <h5 className='p-4' style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                <Link to="about" spy={true} smooth={true} duration={800} onClick={() => {}}>about</Link>
              </h5>
              <h5 className='p-4' style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                <Link to="services" spy={true} smooth={true} duration={800} onClick={() => {}}>services</Link>
              </h5>
              <h5 className='p-4' style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                <Link to="my-work" spy={true} smooth={true} duration={800} onClick={() => {}}>my work</Link>
              </h5>
              <h5 className='p-4' style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                <Link to="contact" spy={true} smooth={true} duration={800} onClick={() => {}}>contact</Link>
              </h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="snap-start bg-gray h-screen" id='about'>
        </div>

        <div className="snap-start bg-beige h-screen" id='services'>
        </div>

        <div className="snap-start bg-gray h-screen" id='my-work'>
        </div>

        <div className="snap-start bg-beige h-screen" id='contact'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did and it works now

```html
'use client'
import Image from 'next/image'

export default function Home() {
  const handleClickAbout = () => {
    const element = document.getElementById('about');
    if (element) {
      element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  };

  const handleClickServices = () => {
    const element = document.getElementById('services');
    if (element) {
      element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  };

  const handleClickWork = () => {
    const element = document.getElementById('my-work');
    if (element) {
      element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  };

  const handleClickContact = () => {
    const element = document.getElementById('contact');
    if (element) {
      element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <div className='snap-y snap-mandatory h-screen w-screen overflow-y-scroll'>
        <div className="snap-start bg-beige h-screen">
          <div className='flex justify-between pl-3 pr-3'>
            <div className='relative h-14 w-14 md:h-16 md:w-16'>
              <Image
                src="/logo-gray.png"
                layout="fill"
                objectFit="cover"
                alt="Logo"
              />
            </div>
            <div className='flex items-center'>
              <h5 className='p-4'>
                <button onClick={handleClickAbout}>about</button>
              </h5>
              <h5 className='p-4'>
                <button onClick={handleClickServices}>services</button>
              </h5>
              <h5 className='p-4'>
                <button onClick={handleClickWork}>my work</button>
              </h5>
              <h5 className='p-4'>
                <button onClick={handleClickContact}>contact</button>
              </h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="snap-start bg-gray h-screen" id='about'>
        </div>

        <div className="snap-start bg-beige h-screen" id='services'>
        </div>

        <div className="snap-start bg-gray h-screen" id='my-work'>
        </div>

        <div className="snap-start bg-beige h-screen" id='contact'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```